# TypeScript's Linked Files are unseen by current project's TypeScript files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I've completed rewritting my javascript framework project in TypeScript. Now I'm trying to use these files in many other web projects.

I've tried linking (Linked File) them into the web project. First thing I noticed, I can't change the Build Action to "TypeScriptCompile". .ts files are compiled in their source folder, not where they are linked. The problem is that when creating a new file .ts file in web project, it doesn't see the linked files and I get a TypeScript error.

Also, everytime I try to build a project with Linked TypeScript Files, it crashes Visual Studio.

I'm using AMD and RequireJS. The structure needs to be respected. I'm setting the baseURL to /Scripts/ and my framework and TS files need to be inside that structure.

Does anyone have any idea ?

---

Here's a sample of what I'm trying

Content from **Linked File** from a Framework project:

```
export class Log {
  static error (msg: string) { console.log(msg); }
}
```

Content from **File in web project** using Linked File:

```
import fw = module('linkedFile');
fw.Log.error('this file can\'t find the linked file, so this code won\t work');
```

Thanks !

**UPDATE:** 
The only way I found so far is to copy Frameworks files from the source project to my web project on Post Build:

```
xcopy /y /e /s /d "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\." "$(ProjectDir)..\..\OtherProject\Scripts\."
```

The problem with this is we have to edit framework files in the first project, otherwise, our changes will be overwritten.

**UPDATE 2:**
I'm currently using this script to automatically copy all linked files where they are in the project. You need to edit your CSPROJ file and it has to be a WEB Project. Check the link for a complete description:

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesdawson/archive/2008/06/03/using-linked-files-with-web-application-projects.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

```
  <!-- ======================== -->
  <!-- Copy linked files -->
  <Target Name="_CopyLinkedContentFiles">
    <!-- Remove any old copies of the files -->
    <Delete Condition=" '%(Content.Link)' != '' AND Exists('$(WebProjectOutputDir)\%(Content.Link)') " Files="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\%(Content.Link)" />
    <!-- Copy linked content files recursively to the project folder -->
    <Copy Condition=" '%(Content.Link)' != '' " SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" DestinationFiles="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\%(Content.Link)" />
  </Target>
  <!-- Override the default target dependencies to -->
  <!-- include the new _CopyLinkedContentFiles target. -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PrepareForRunDependsOn>
      $(PrepareForRunDependsOn);
      _CopyWebApplication;
      _CopyLinkedContentFiles;
      _BuiltWebOutputGroupOutput
    </PrepareForRunDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- <PostBuildEvent>$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe "$(ProjectDir)_build\site.xml"</PostBuildEvent> -->
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- ======================== -->
```

Answer (score 1):

When you link a file the path is still relative to its actual location, so you'd have to use a whole bunch of ../../../ to get there.

One option is to set the file to copy on build so it will be copied to your bin folder. I do this for tests but not for releasable code.

Another option is to package your modules to make it easier to use particular versions. You could use a private NuGet repo to do this.

Comment: What I did after posting this question was to xcopy the files from $(ProjectPath) to all my websites on post build. This works but we need to remember to modify only the source files because they will be overwritten. I think the Nuget package would be the best solution, aside from TypeScript actually supporting LinkedFiles. I'll try it and let you know. Thanks !

Comment: Actually, not sure Nuget package would actually work because I'm using AMD and RequireJS. The structure needs to be respected. I'm setting the baseURL to Scripts and my framework and new TS files need to be inside that structure. Thanks again.

Comment: Check out the NuGet packages from the Definitely Typed guys - puts each script in the correct file location and can get you any deoendencies you need all in one go.